# Значение массива выводится некорректно

Tags: java

У меня есть функция, которая делает нужные мне переменные и записывает их в массив, где-то облажался, помогите разобраться что именно не так.

```
public static int[] getDate(Parser pa) {
        String next = pa.returnA3().get(0).replaceAll("['/]", "");
        int[]datearr = new int [3];
        String day="";
        String month="";
        String year="";
        char  ch1; char ch5;
        char ch2; char ch6;
        char ch3;char ch7;
        char ch4;char ch8;
        ch1 = next.charAt(0);
        ch2 = next.charAt(1);
        day = Character.toString(ch1);
        day+=Character.toString(ch2);
        ch3 = next.charAt(2);
        ch4 = next.charAt(3);
        month = Character.toString(ch3);
        month+= Character.toString(ch4);
        ch5 = next.charAt(4);
        ch6 = next.charAt(5);
        ch7 = next.charAt(6);
        ch8 = next.charAt(7);
        year = Character.toString(ch5);
        year += Character.toString(ch6);
        year += Character.toString(ch7);
        year += Character.toString(ch8);
        
        datearr[0]= Integer.parseInt(day);
        datearr[1] = Integer.parseInt(month);
        datearr[2] = Integer.parseInt(year);
        return datearr;
    }
```

Строка, которую я получаю, имеет вид '12/18/1950.
Я удаляю лишние символы и формирую числа из чаров, что не так ?
Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что я допустил ошибку при вызове элемента, не указав индекс массива))

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вы пробуете превратить массив в строку, что-то вроде такого:

```
int[] result = getDate(pa);
String str = result.toString();
```

или пробуете напечатать массив:

```
System.out.println(result);
```

В этом случае используется реализация `toString` по-умолчанию, и для массивов она работает таким неочевидным образом.

Чтоб превратить весь массив в удобочитаемую строку используйте `Arrays.toString`:

```
String str = Arrays.toString(result);
```