# В консоль получаю [I@50040f0c, вместо массива - Java

Tags: java

Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arrayResult = readArray();
        System.out.print(arrayResult);
    }

    public static int[] readArray () {
        int [] arr;
        int n;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = in.nextInt();
        arr = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        return  arr;
    }
```

Comment: Функция сама ничего "не показывает в консоле". Чтобы вывести что-то в консоль, надо написать для этого код.

Comment: Но эта же функция возвращает массив с помощью ```return  arr```

Comment: Почему Вы решили, что "возвращать из функции" это то же самое, что "выводить в консоль"?

Comment: Мне так приснилось сегодня

Comment: А почему я вместо результата получаю это - [I@50040f0c?

Comment: Нам плохо видно Ваш код через интернет.

Comment: Это странно, все правильно написал и получаю это, а не результат

Comment: Неправильно написали.

Comment: Вот код: https://prnt.sc/17hmdds

Comment: Код - в вопрос.

Comment: Здесь ограничение по времени

Comment: Я не понимаю, что Вы говорите.

Comment: Я могу задавать вопрос каждые 40 минут

Comment: У Вас уже есть вопрос, который Вы можете редактировать. Ссылка "Править" - под вопросом.

Comment: Ок, сейчас отредактирую, ждите

Comment: Почему Вы решили, что `System.out.print(arrayResult);` выведет то, что Вам надо? Кстати, что Вам надо?

Comment: Так как ```arrayResult``` и есть массив, получен с помощью функции ```readArray```, мне нужен мой массив, который я ввел с помощью функции

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Значение массива выводится некорректно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1295284/%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be)

Answer (score 1):

Функция сама ничего "не показывает в консоле". Чтобы вывести что-то в консоль, надо написать для этого код.

```
int[] result = readArray();
// output result ...
for (int r : result) {
  System.out.println(r);
}
```

Comment: Я не понимаю эту сокращенную версию цикла ```for```

Comment: @VladyslavVerong, даже интуитивно никаких идей нет?

Comment: Нет, потому что я новичок

Comment: Кстати когда в цикле одна строчка, то ``` {  } ``` не нужны, это только нагружает программу

Comment: @VladyslavVerong https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp

Comment: @VladyslavVerong "это только нагружает программу" - не следует употреблять слова, смысла которых Вы не понимаете

Comment: Спасибо, просто я новичок

Comment: @VladyslavVerong чем нагружает?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы понять, откуда берется `[I@50040f0c`, заглянем в реализацию метода `print()`. Там вы увидите что-то вроде:

```java
public void print(Object obj) {
    this.write(obj == null ? "null" : obj.toString());
}
```

То есть, когда мы делаем `print(array)`, под капотом вызывается `array.toString()`.

Теперь глянем, что делает метод `toString()`:

```java
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(this.hashCode());
}
```

Получается, что при распечатывании массивов с помощью `print()` мы на самом деле распечатываем не содержимое этого массива, а нечто, что называется [хэш-кодом](https://habr.com/en/post/168195/) объекта.

Чтобы распечатать содержимое массива, используйте хелпер `Arrays.toString()`:

```java
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arrayResult));
```